# PHP Imagick median filter deprecated

Tags: filter, deprecated, imagick, median

PHP Imagick throws:

```
medianFilterImage method is deprecated and it's use should be avoided
```

but I can't find a replacement for controlled noise reduction with Imagick.
Any suggestions?

I've tried Imagick::despeckleImage() but it has not controls.

[PHP Version 5.4.20] [Imagick module version 3.3.0RC2]

Answer (score 0):

I am never sure if there are exact replacements for deprecated functions in ImageMagick but Imagick::statisticImage() is probably what you want with the Imagick::STATISTIC_MEDIAN type set.

An example of it in action can be seen [here](http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/statisticImage?imagePath=Lorikeet&statisticType=4&w20=1.1&h20=1.1&channel=134217727) Both of the parameters are meant to be able to set to floating point values.

Comment: Thanks! It works like it is the right one and provides better control. I will try the other _type_ _geometry_ values. There are some few poor documented methods for (PHP) Imagick and sometimes one must guess syntax  from ImageMagick command line documentation.

Comment: btw you "might" want to run the script through valgrind to check for memory errors, just in case. I think ImageMagick had a bug in it for some versions. So if you just make a test script that does the processing and then process it with "valgrind /usr/bin/php test_script.php" it will check that the version of ImageMagick you're using doesn't have a mem bug for that function. I can't remember if that function is actually affected or not.....just a hunch.

Comment: Oh, and the statistic types: https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/blob/master/imagick_helpers.c#L1677-L1686